# cplusplus importing csv does not recognise first column?

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file into my c++ program but I am having a few problems and would like some clarification.

The data in the csv file is arranged like below. As you can see there are 12 cells that I would like to import.

```
x, y, z, p
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
```

My function to import said csv file is the following:

```
  while ( getline (myfile, stringg, ','))
    {          
        std::cout << "j: " << j << "  " << stringg << std::endl;

        j++; //Note: j counts each cell.
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Everything imports perfectly fine. However it seems j has stopped counting. This shouldn't be the case since the number in the csv file is still being printed.

```
j: 0 x
j: 1 y
j: 2 z 
j: 3 p
1
j: 4 2
j: 5 3
j: 6 4
5
j: 7 6
j: 8 7
j: 9 8
```

Now I know why I believe it's doing that. The end of each line does not have a comma at the end. However! This still does not account for why j stopped counting?

Comment: @Excelcius Kindly do not edit posts to change the coding style to your personal preference. Coding style is very subjective and there is often no right or wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "j stopped counting"? I see a strictly ascending sequence from j:0 to j:9 ...

Comment: @Lundin Ok thanks I get your point, but the indentation is unnecessary, there is just an unneeded closing bracket at the end. Anyway, my main concern was the wrong cout statement

Comment: Your delimiting character in your `getline` call is `','`, which means that `stringg` (when reading the last column) contains the last column, the first column, and the `'\n'` in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

count of `j` is correct... if you take a closer look your file will be like this

```
x, y, z, p'\n'
1, 2, 3, 4'\n'
5, 6, 7, 8'\n'
```

So when you when the value of `j is 3` line read by `getline()` is `p'\n'1` which when printed on console as

```
j: 3 p
1
```

after that j is incremented and next token read in `2`...same for rest..

Comment: Ah beautiful! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` is reading the input until the next `','` character. In your case, this means that `stringg` will contain this:

```
1. iteration: stringg == "x"
2. iteration: stringg == " y"
3. iteration: stringg == " z"
4. iteration: stringg == " p\n1" // The fourth string contains the next line!
```

Errors like these should be easily visible when debugging the program.

One approach to solve this problem could be to read line by line using the default `getline` and inside this loop split the resulting string into further parts using `','` as the separator.